# Are pop songs often composed on "layers" and is there a common set of layers used in pop music?

Tags: composition

I was reading [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8276/common-names-for-sections-of-a-piece-of-music/8281) and [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/21960/song-structure-whats-up-with-verse-chorus-verse-2-chorus-verse-3-bridge-chorus), both of which discuss the parts that are often present in a piece of music as it progresses from beginning to end.

The question I wanted to ask is about the "layers" that can be present in a musical piece from the beginning to the end. For example many pop songs have a (often, some repeating drum) beat in the background and vocals more on the foreground.

1. Is there a proper term for these layers?
2. Is there a "typical set" of these layers that would commonly be
   present in pop songs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call "layers," the rest of the music world calls "arrangement."  And yes, genres of music are built around distinct commonalities of arrangement.